# Method of finding threshold in Decision tree for continuous data

Tags: machine-learning, weka, decision-tree

I am using decision tree in Weka and I have some continuous data, so when I use Weka it automatically find the threshold for me but for some reason I want to implement Decision Tree by myself so I need to know what approach to use to find the threshold to discretize my continuous data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) and [C4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) use [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) heuristic for discretization of continuous data. The method finds a binary cut for each variable (feature). You could apply the same method recursively to get multiple intervals from continuous data.

Suppose at a certain tree node, all instances belong to a set of `S`, and you are working on variable `A` and a particular boundary (cut) `T`, the class information entropy of the partition induced by `T`, denoted as `E(A,T,S)` is given by:

```
             |S1|                 |S2|
E(A, T, S) = ---- Entropy(S1) +   ---- Entropy(S2)
              |S|                 |S|
```

where `|S1|` is the number of instances in the first partition; `|S2|` is the number of instances in the second partition; `|S| = |S1|+|S2|`.

For a given feature `A`, the boundary `T_min` which minimizes the entropy function over all possible partition boundaries, is selected as a binary discretization boundary.

For example, you might have a variable `Length`, with all possible values as:

```
Length = {2.1, 2.8, 3.5, 8.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 51.0}
```

Then your `T` could be:

```
T = {2.1, 2.8, 3.5, 8.0, 10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 51.0}
```

in which you cut at every possible `Length` value. You could also cut at every middle point of adjacent `Length` values, e.g.,

```
T = {2.45, 3.15, 5.75, 9.0, 15.0, 35.0, 50.5}
```

At discretization time, you will iterate through all possible `T` values and evaluate which one obtains the minimum `E(A, T, S)`. That's it.

See more details in this [paper](http://www.ibai-institut.de/files/sspr98.pdf), which also describes other optional methods:

- ChiMerge Discretization method.
- Learning Vector Quantization (LVQ) based method
- Histogram-based method.