# How is the Gini-Index minimized in CART Algorithm for Decision Trees?

Tags: optimization, neural-network, cart, decision-tree, backpropagation

For neural networks for example I minimize the cost function by using the backpropagation algorithm. Is there something equivalent for the Gini Index in decision trees?

CART Algorithm always states "choose partition of set A, that minimizes Gini-Index", but how to I actually get that partition mathematically?

Any input on this would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a decision tree, there are different methods for splitting continuous variables like age, weight, income, etc.

A) Discretize the continuous variable to use it as a categorical variable in all aspects of the DT algorithm. This can be done:

- only once during the start and then keeping this discretization
  static
- at every stage where a split is required, using percentiles or
  interval ranges or clustering to bucketize the variable

B) Split at all possible distinct values of the variable and see where there is the highest decrease in the Gini Index. This can be computationally expensive. So, there are optimized variants where you sort the variables and instead of choosing all distinct values, choose the midpoints between two consecutive values as the splits. For example, if the variable 'weight' has 70, 80, 90 and 100 kgs in the data points, try 75, 85, 95 as splits and pick the best one (highest decrease in Gini or other impurities)

But then, what is the exact split algorithm that is implemented in *scikit-learn in python*, *rpart in R*, and the *mlib package in pyspark* , and what are the differences between them in the splitting of a continuous variable is something I am not sure as well and am still researching.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://sefiks.com/2018/08/27/a-step-by-step-cart-decision-tree-example/) there is a good example of CART algorithm. Basically, we get the gini index like this:

[image: gini]

For each attribute we have different values each of which will have a gini index, according to the class they belong to. For example, if we had two classes (positive and negative), each value of an attribute will have some records that belong to the positive class and some other values that belong to the negative class. So we can calculate the probabilities. Say if an attribute was called **weather** and it had two values (e.g. **rainy** and **sunny**), and we had these information:

- rainy: 2 positive, 3 negative
- sunny: 1 positive, 2 negative

we could say:

- [image: gsunny]
- [image: grainy]

Then we can have the weighted sum of gini indexes for **weather** (assuming we had a total of 8 records):

[image: sum]

We do this for all the other attributes (like we did for weather) and at the end we choose the attribute with the lowest gini index to be the one to split the tree from. We have to do all this at each split (unless we could classify the sub-tree without the need for splitting).

Comment: Thanks Hadi for the Input :) However I am wondering how that works for non categorical values like I got a big data set containing a persons salary, weight and height all in real numbers and want to predict its gender. Does the algorithm really compute each split of height (n possabilities  for n people) manually and compares them?
For Dataset of N persons, A attributes I need to calculate A\cdot N different coefficients.

Comment: For non-categorical data, you can split the data with a threshold. There is a better explanation [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/32623/78192). You have two output classes (male, female) and three attributes. You can set thresholds to split the values of salary, weight and height or as you said let the algorithm compute each split and get the best (explained better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510612/6129428).